# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an app that imports js-common library created by me. This library exports several components. When I try to import one of them in my app I get:

"Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ListComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(ListComponent) in connect options."

If I move this component (the file) in my app it's working. So the problem is when I export from the library.
In my library I'm using babel to transform every file.

**UPDATED**

WORK

```
import ListComponent from "./ListComponent";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      </ListComponent>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

DOES NOT WORK

```
import ListComponent from "js-common";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      </ListComponent>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here, from what I can understand, is that you have used react-redux for state management which requires you to wrap your root component with the `Provider` component that ships with react-redux. It works in your app because you have probably provided the store in that app but when  you export it, you don't have a store in whatever place you import it in.

If you are trying to write a library to be exported, then you would be better off not using redux...Or, at the very least, you need to provide a Provider to the top level component you intend to ship. The `Provider` is used like this.

```
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Component />
    </Provider>
```

where `store` is the redux store you are using

Comment: I already have the provider in my root component. I don't see the difference between exporting the same component from app or library. It should work because I'm importing it in app. Take a look the code I wrote it down now